# AM-GM Inequality. Let a, b, c be positive real numbers. Prove that $ \frac {a+b+c}{3} \cdot (a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge a^2b + b^2c + c^2a$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that $$ \frac {a+b+c}{3} \cdot \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3} \ge \frac{a^2b + b^2c + c^2a}{3}$$.
given that a,b,c are positive real numbers.
Solve only using **AM-GM**. 
So far I have tried expanding LHS, and simplifying to:$$a^3+b^3+c^3+ab^2+bc^2+ca^2 \ge 2(a^2b + b^2c + c^2a)$$
However this has not lead me anywhere.
Source:  [Basics Of Inequality](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/161/articles/Riasat_BasicsOlympiadInequalities.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

HINT

(You made an excellent start.)

Apply the AM-GM inequality to $\frac{c^3+ca^2}{2}$

Comment: Thanks, now I am able to solve it. Can you explain your intuition?

Comment: I guess I just spotted that these two terms had a product that was a relevant square.